# Jquery show/hide button not working

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-24 columns row2 darkgreybg" id="ricontainer">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>

  $(function() {
    $("#ributton").click(function () {
        // Hide it but only if not hidden - hide
        $('#ricontainer:visible').hide();

        // Later in the script - Show it but only If it's not visible.  
        $('#ricontainer:hidden').show();
    });
  });
```

No idea why this isn't working, any ideas? I just want it so that I have a container that if visible, when a button is clicked it will hide it. Or, if it is already hidden, when the button is clicked it will show it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this code is hide and show. where is the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggle()` instead:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#ributton").click(function () {
        $('#ricontainer').toggle(); // toggles between show/hide
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Jai's suggestion you could use .toggle() but I always find toggling ends in tears.

```
$(function() {
    $("#ributton").click(function () {

        if($('#ricontainer').is(':visible'))
        {
           // Hide it but only if not hidden - hide
           $('#ricontainer').hide();
        }
        else
        {
           $('#ricontainer').show();
        }
    });
  });
```

You should also probably be using "on" rather than "click" as I believe this is the recommended approach as of version 1.7 of jQuery:

```
$('#ributton').on('click', function(){});
```

Comment: The issue being that in certain situations you end up creating a scenario where the toggling can become reversed when there are multiple fields controlling the visibility of the "toggled" field

Answer (score 0):

You code will always show the button, here is why:

Button initially hidden:

```
$('#ricontainer:visible').hide(); // nothing happens, button not selected
                                  // because the selector matches nothing

$('#ricontainer:hidden').show();  // hidden button found and shown, all good
```

Button initally shown:

```
$('#ricontainer:visible').hide(); // selector matched, button found
                                  // now hiding the button

$('#ricontainer:hidden').show();  // button hidden from the previous line is found
                                  // so the selector matched and is now showing the button
                                  // and that's the PROBLEM
```

The other answers already suggest ways how to fix it, this is just showing you why it doesn't work as you expect. So, either fetch the state of the button at the beginning and use if/else to change its state, or simply toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript like:

```
...
<div class="large-24 columns row2 darkgreybg" id="ricontainer" onclick="controlButton()">
...

function controlButton() {
      var div = document.getElementById("ricontainer");
      if (div.style.display === "none") {
         div.style.display = "block";
      } else {
         div.style.display = "none";
      }
}
```